# Automatically infer type of req.params when Express request handler is defined outside routing method

Tags: typescript, express

When I define a request handler inside a call to some Express routing method, Typescript is able to infer the structure of the `req.params` object from the route:

```js
import express from "express";
let app = express();

app.get("/:abc", (req, res) => {
    // req.params is inferred to be type { abc: string }
    let abc = req.params.abc; // this typechecks - good
    let xyz = req.params.xyz; // this doesn't - good
})
```

But when I define a request handler outside of the call to the routing method, Express doesn't infer the type:

```js
import express, { RequestHandler } from "express";
let app = express();

let requestHandler: RequestHandler = (req, res) => {
    // req.params is inferred to be type ParamsDictionary
    // which is equal to {[key: string]: string}
    // and thus too generic
    let abc = req.params.abc; // this typechecks - good
    let xyz = req.params.xyz; // this shouldn't, but does - bad
}
app.get("/:abc", requestHandler)
```

`RequestHandler` optionally accepts generics to type parts of the request and response, so I can get it to type check the params by explicitly passing a `RouteParameters` type with the route string:

```js
import express, { RequestHandler } from "express";
import { RouteParameters } from "express-serve-static-core/index.js";
let app = express();

let requestHandler: RequestHandler<RouteParameters<"/:abc">> = (req, res) => {
    // now typescript can infer that req.params is type { abc: string }
    let abc = req.params.abc; // this typechecks - good
    let xyz = req.params.xyz; // this doesn't - good
};
app.get("/:abc", requestHandler);
```

But this requires me to type the same route twice. This isn't a huge deal, but I don't like that there's no type checking to ensure that the route I pass to the route method is the same as the route I pass to `RouteParameters`. If I change this code to

```js
let requestHandler: RequestHandler<RouteParameters<"/:abc">> = (req, res) => {
    let abc = req.params.abc; // this typechecks - bad
};
app.get("/:jkl", requestHandler); // changed here
```

I don't get a type error, which makes sense but is not ideal. Additionally, if I ever wanted to add more type checking to my request handlers by adding additional interfaces, I might have to type the route in more than two places.

Is there any way to get a request handler defined outside of a routing method call to infer the type of req.params, without explicitly passing the `RouteParameters<"route-string">` generic type to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but traditionally what I've done is wrap my dynamic handler function in another one that accepts an app:

```
import { Express } from "express";

const requestHandlerFor = (app: Express) => app.get("/:abc", ...);

// ...

requestHandlerFor(app);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What's the benefit of making a function that takes an Express app and attaches a request handler inside the function, as opposed to at the top level?

Comment: @GalenLong Then you won't have to deal with the problem you have described?

Comment: Ah, okay, I think I understand what you're saying. My use case for wanting to do this is that I wanted to make API functions that took params/query/request bodies as args and returned a status/body, and then have a generic function take the API func and return an Express request handler that calls the API func and sends a response using the body/status it returns (this is so I can type my API functions more strictly, prohibiting things like sending empty bodies). So what you're saying wouldn't work for my exact use case, but it makes sense in general. Anyway, thank you!